# Localhost requests to mixpanel being "cancelled"

Tags: javascript, analytics, mixpanel, kissmetrics

In an attempt to test with mixpanel analytics locally, I am experiencing an issue with requests being cancelled (status code: 0).

Troubleshooting:

- Verified that api token is correct
- Mixpanel project settings use local domain
- Requests work if copied and ran in browser tab

(Note: I set up KISSmetrics for local testing with no issues)

Comment: I get the exact same issue, not sure why. Works on production. http://cl.ly/image/1N1d1X2h1y2U

Answer (score 2):

Cancelled means that the page is moving before the request is completed. This is very common when you attach a Mixpanel event to a link click or form submission event.

You can avoid this by using [track_links()](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.track_links) or [track_forms()](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.track_forms)